# Convert pandas dataframe with 2D data in each row to tensorflow dataset

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I have pandas dataframe with 340 columns and each row for every 10 minutes.
I want to train a model by converting this data into 2D array by combining 6 rows for an hour. So that I will have 6*340 shape data for corresponding hourly labels (to be predicted values).

#### Initial Dataset:

[image: This is the initial dataset]

```
grouped_data = []
for i in mnts:
    for j in days:
        for k in hrs:
            for l in ids:
                if (len(data[(data['id']==l) & (data['hour'] == k) & (data['day']==j) & (data['month']==i)])) > 0:
                    grouped_data.append([l,i,j,k,np.asarray(data[(data['id']==l) & (data['hour'] == k) & (data['day']==j) & (data['month']==i)][feature_colz]).astype('float32')])

df2 = pd.DataFrame(grouped_data,columns = ['id','month','day','hour','feats'])
```

#### Resulting Dataframe

[image: I get this dataframe]

```
df2.feats.shape       # it will give (45105,)
df2.feats[0].shape    # it will give (6,340)

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((np.asarray(df2['feats']).astype(np.float32), target.values))
```

when I convert it to tensorflow dataset it gives the following error-

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

#### Data in Dataframe

[image: this is the data in the dataframe]

Answer (score 0):

Use the [values](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) property of the pandas DataFrame.

```
df2.values
```